# update column table(table has duplicates) with values of another column table

Tags: sql, netezza

I need to update a column in a table(table has duplicates)  with values of another table . I tried couple of codes but it gives me error

> ERROR:  Update canceled: attempt to update a target row with values
>   from multiple join rows

Here is my code:

```
UPDATE SERGIU_BI_CCM_AGG_MTH t1
  SET t1.CURRENT_SEC = foo.CURRENT_SEC
  FROM (
  SELECT t1a.sub_id, t1a.CURRENT_BRAND, t2.CURRENT_SEC, t2.from_date,      
  t2.to_date
  FROM SERGIU_BI_CCM_AGG_MTH t1a
     LEFT JOIN BI_CCM_BASE t2
     ON t1a.sub_id = t2.sub_id and t1a.CURRENT_BRAND = t2.CURRENT_BRAND
  )
  foo 
WHERE t1.sub_id = foo.sub_id and t1.CURRENT_BRAND = foo.CURRENT_BRAND    
 and  t1.agg_mth between to_char(foo.from_date,'YYYYMM') and   
 to_char(foo.to_date-1,'YYYYMM');
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duplicates are causing the error, lets get unique record for each `sub_id` and `CURRENT_BRAND` using `row_number()`.

try below query

```
UPDATE SERGIU_BI_CCM_AGG_MTH t1
SET t1.CURRENT_SEC = foo.CURRENT_SEC
FROM (
        SELECT t1a.sub_id
            , t1a.CURRENT_BRAND
            , t2.CURRENT_SEC
            , t2.from_date
            , t2.to_date
            , row_number() over (partition by t1a.sub_id,CURRENT_BRAND order by from_date desc) as rn
        FROM SERGIU_BI_CCM_AGG_MTH t1a
        LEFT JOIN BI_CCM_BASE t2 ON t1a.sub_id = t2.sub_id 
            and t1a.CURRENT_BRAND = t2.CURRENT_BRAND
      )foo 
WHERE t1.sub_id = foo.sub_id 
    and t1.CURRENT_BRAND = foo.CURRENT_BRAND    
    and t1.agg_mth between to_char(foo.from_date,'YYYYMM') and to_char(foo.to_date-1,'YYYYMM');
    and foo.rn = 1
```

Comment: ERROR:  Column reference "SUB_ID" is ambiguous this message shows in netezza

Comment: The query works but i don't see any changes in the table SERGIU_BI_CCM_AGG_MTH

Comment: try to select first before doing the update. if there's no result on the select, it means, there's no matching record based on your criteria. btw, what's the datatype of yoru to_date and from_date fields?

Comment: YEs you are right , i checked and the are Null values in the column, i will populate with sub_id that has values other values to see if it updated

Comment: May you how i could change this script with ROWID, Somethig like this Create table Sergiu as  select Rowid from...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use these 2 below ways:

- with "join"

```sql
UPDATE SERGIU_BI_CCM_AGG_MTH t1
    LEFT JOIN BI_CCM_BASE t2
        ON t1.sub_id = t2.sub_id and t1.CURRENT_BRAND = t2.CURRENT_BRAND
  SET t1.CURRENT_SEC = t2.CURRENT_SEC
WHERE t1.agg_mth between to_char(t2.from_date,'YYYYMM') and   
 to_char(t2.to_date-1,'YYYYMM');
```

- without "join":

```sql
UPDATE SERGIU_BI_CCM_AGG_MTH t1, BI_CCM_BASE t2
  SET t1.CURRENT_SEC = t2.CURRENT_SEC
WHERE t1.sub_id = t2.sub_id and t1.CURRENT_BRAND = t2.CURRENT_BRAND 
 and  t1.agg_mth between to_char(t2.from_date,'YYYYMM') and   
 to_char(t2.to_date-1,'YYYYMM');
```

Hope this can help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need the following query.

```
    UPDATE SERGIU_BI_CCM_AGG_MTH t1
    SET t1.CURRENT_SEC = (SELECT  t2.CURRENT_SEC   
    FROM SERGIU_BI_CCM_AGG_MTH t1a
    LEFT JOIN BI_CCM_BASE t2
    ON t1a.sub_id = t2.sub_id and t1a.CURRENT_BRAND = t2.CURRENT_BRAND
WHERE t1.sub_id = foo.sub_id and t1.CURRENT_BRAND = foo.CURRENT_BRAND    
      and  t1.agg_mth between to_char(foo.from_date,'YYYYMM') and   
      to_char(foo.to_date-1,'YYYYMM'))
```

Comment: Netezza don't support correlated queries :) , thank you